# secondary HDD problems with gnome

Tags: 12.10, gnome, 64-bit, hard-drive

I have two HDDs running in my computer,however when I logon using GNOME,the drives do not appear unless I logout,log back in using the default ubuntu shell,open the drives,then logout and back in with the GNOME shell.I tried using gparted to mount the drives,but the option is greyed out.I am using ubuntu 12.10 64 bit.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the contents of your /etc/fstab file. so that we can provide you with the solution.

Comment: UUID=574ee6f2-14a6-4b7c-8048-4a6d0f36f101 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=5de749ae-a91f-4a59-94b8-1ddd7dbed88d none            swap    sw              0       0

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it to your fstab file so it mounts hen you boot. You can just edit /etc/fstab as root and add it... Here is a quick guide to get you going.

Drop to a terminal prompt

Use `blkid` to get the uuid (you could just use /dev/sdX, but this is better because if you move stuff around, linux still knows what drive you mean)

Make your additions, ctrl-o (the letter) and hit enter to save, ctrl-x to exit

reboot or `sudo mount -a` to see changes.

`sudo nano /etc/fstab` and add the drive. here are examples...

UUID=my-uuid-goes-here /media/ntfs ntfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,allow_other 0 0
UUID=my-home-drive-uuid-happens-to-go-here /home           ext4    defaults 0 2

Comment: nothing happens when I type blkid into the terminal

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your other drives are not mounted automatically.you should first check if the drive is showing as sdb or sda or sdc or something like that from /dev directory. if you face any problems detecting that past the out-put of below command in here. before you proceed DO NOT DO TRIAL AND ERRORS IT MAY CRASH THE SYSTEM.

```
# ls /dev/*
```

---

**once you find the dive file go ahead with below steps.**

I would suggest that you mount those drives manually using below command.

```
# sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

now in this command /dev/sdb1 shows that you are mounting your secound HDD. sdb 1 stands for storage device 'b' & 1 stands for 1st partition of that HDD, so on & on ... if it was 1st HDD then it would have been sda1. now last part of this command is the destination folder where you want that drive to be mounted, so you can create that folder with any name and use it.

now once you mount it. follow below commands to make sure that it is auto mounted each time.

```
# su -
```

enter the password for root, so that you will become Super-Admin, then..

```
# vi /etc/fstab
```

enter the below line in that file after the two lines that you pasted in the above comment.

```
 /dev/sdb1    /mnt      ext3    defaults     0        2
```

use tab to give spaces for each column shown above. then save the file and then use below command to make sure that it is done without the errors.

```
# mount -a
```

IF THIS COMMAND SHOWS SOME ERRORS THEN REMOVE THE CHANGES MADE IN THE /etc/fstab AND UPDATE ME! after that please use the above command to check if the changes are removed correctly. if it still shows the error then DO NOT RESTART OR SHUT DOWN THE SYSTEM AS IF YOU DO SO IT WILL NEVER RESTART WITHOUT SOME HEAVY TROUBLESHOOTING. once the command shows no errors then it's done correctly.

let me know if this solves your issue permanently.